# Skip Integers for lab activity

Tags: python, function, if-statement

1. Define a function named skip_integers, with a variable number of arguments.
2. Use a for loop to iterate over the arguments.
3. Use a check to see whether the value passed is of the integer type. If it is, use the continue statement to ignore it.
4. Print the arguments.

```
def skip_integers(*args):
     for i in args:
         if i == (function)
         continue

skip_integers(3,5.2, "value", 6.0)
```

I cant figure this out at all can someone help me:(

Comment: i cant print out the skip_integers staement at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the code you've shown, so it must be with the if-statement. Not knowing what your function is doing, I created my own.

```
   def is_integer(num): 
        if type(num) == int:
            return True 
        else: 
            return False
```

You could also simplify this by adding the if statement in my function to your code like this.

```
    for i in args:
        if type(i) == int:
             continue
```

Comment: that is working but i need to be able to print out: 5.2 value 6.0

Comment: this is due soon so if you are avaible i need all the time i have

Comment: @Pianoman_4 add else: print(i) under the if statement. I can edit my post if need be.

Answer (score 0):

```py
user_string = input()    # prompt the user to enter the string    
result = user_string.isdigit()    # check if the string is an integer string

if result:    # if result is true then print yes
    print("yes")
else:    # else if result is false then print no
   print("no")
```

Comment: Formatting the provided solution using stackoverflow's Markdown capabilities is the preferred way of supplying an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
# defining the skip_integers with a variable number of arguments. 
def skip_integers (*num):  
    for i in num:  # for loop to iterate the arguments
        if type(i) == int:  # Checking for integer type
            continue
        print(i)    # print the value of non-integers

skip_integers(5.2,"value", 6.0) # print the arguments
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

this works:

```
def skip_integers(*args):
    args = list(args)
    for i in args:
        if type(i) == int:
            args.remove(i)
    return args
```

Comment: Is not working because at the bottom i have : skip_integers(3, 5.2, "value", 6.0) and it says tuple object has no attribute to remove